# Conexao de banco navcat

Tags: php, html, mysql

Gostaria de resolver um problema de conexão de dados no navcat. Não consigo enviar os dados para o banco e não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, se alguém puder me dar algumas sugestões, a conexão é *mysql*.

config.php:

```
<?php 
$config = array(
    'title'  => 'Via Toscana',
    'test'   => 1, /* 1 em testes 0 em produção. */
    'errors' => 1,
    'rewrite' => 0
    );

if($config['test'] == 1) {
    $config['db_host'] = 'dev';
    $config['db_base'] = 'via';
    $config['db_user'] = 'via';
    $config['db_pass'] = 'abc123';
}else{
    $config['db_host'] = 'dev';
    $config['db_base'] = 'via';
    $config['db_user'] = 'via';
    $config['db_pass'] = 'abc123';
}

class objConexao {
    private $objConn;
    public function __construct() {
        global $config;
        $this->objConn = mysql_connect($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass']) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        $link = mysql_select_db($config['db_base'], $this->objConn);

    }
    public function __destruct() {
        @mysql_free_result();
        @mysql_close();
    }
    public function fcnConn(){
        return $this->objConn;
    }
}

$objConn = new objConexao();
$conn = $objConn->fcnConn();
?>
```

Formulário:

1. Sobre</option>-->
                   Cart&atildeo
                   Dinheiro
               
            Your username is for logging in and cannot be changed.</p>-->

   ```
                                   </div>
          <ul class="row">
          <li class="col-sm-12">
          <label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome *" />
           </label>
           </li>
         <li class="col-sm-6">
       <label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail *" />
           </label>
           </li>
           <li class="col-sm-6">
           <label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone *" />
           </label>
           </li>
           <li class="col-sm-12">
           <label>
           <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" rows="5" placeholder="Mensagem *"></textarea>
           </label>
           </li>
           </ul>
       <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
       <input type="submit" id="bt-confirmar"  class="btn btn-default btn-round" value="CONFIRMAR" name="confirmar"/>
       </div>
       </form>
   ```

envia.php:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['cliente_nome'];
$telefone = $_POST['cliente_telefone'];
$email = $_POST['cliente_email'];
$bairro = $_POST['cliente_bairro'];
$rua = $_POST['cliente_rua'];
$complemento = $_POST['cliente_complemento'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$nome', '$telefone', '$email','$bairro','$rua','$complemento')";
echo $sql;exit();
mysql_query($sql,$objConn) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($objConn);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
?>
```

Banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O navicat e uma ferramenta para gestão de banco de dados, não o banco de dados em 
Você utiliza algum programa de servidor local? como o Xampp, VertrigoSrv, Wampp...?

Comment: Não uso local, puxo do ftp direto da hospedagem.

Comment: quando você vai inserir algum dado ele retorna algum erro?

Comment: Já consegui resolver Tech, grato pela atenção.